# Fancybox opening image in a new page

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, fancybox

Me and Fancybox are having a fight right now, and I am losing. When I try to implement Fancybox, instead of opening the image on a pop-out, it opens it on a new page instead. I have my code included below. What could possibly be wrong? I've researched everywhere, and it seems as if it should be working with what I have.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancy-box/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css"     media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancy-box/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">     </script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>



<a class="fancybox" href="rendering_17.jpg"><img src="r17t" alt=""></a>



<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like fancybox isn't being loaded. Are there any errors in the dev console. Try running `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` in the dev console and see if is will work after that. If so then it is being loaded. If not you should inspect the script to see if it actually has the code. Are you sure you put the `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` file in the `js/fancy-box/source/` directory? 

Also, in your case `$(document).ready(function(){}` isn't needed because the script comes after your `<a>` so that `<a>` is already loaded. Not that it matters.

Comment: What's wrong in the code above? : the fancybox js file should be included **AFTER** jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy pasted your code to the [Online Real-time HTML Editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com), changed the includes and it worked for me:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen">
```

Make sure that all of your includes are correct, and don't forget that you should include jQuery first.

Comment: The code of this answer doesn't look like the OP's code at all

Comment: @totymedli : obviously, there are things that are not too obvious to you like hosting issues when you include jQuery plugins before the jQuery itself, the fancybox versions used (which you wouldn't bother to ask for) as well as the repercussions of using the latest version of jQuery (as originally posted) with older versions of fancybox. Nevertheless you ventured to suggest to use a very old version of jQuery without considering if the OP is using another plugin that might not work with that version. You don't get 20K for missing the obvious :P

Comment: by `hosting` I meant to say `hoisting` ;)